# Strange Params Search Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I’m build a search with a query simple. I following step by step the instructions of a tutorial, buy I came across a hash parameters like this when I submit the search form:

`Parameters: { "/path"=>{"query"=>"lorem ipsum dolor"}, ... }`

I think what this problem happening because the form_tag render this input with the attribute name like this:

`<input type="text" name="/path[query]" />`

`<%= form_for questions_path, method: :get, class: "form-horizontal" do | q |%>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= q.text_field :query, placeholder: "Lorem ipsum dolor", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= q.submit class: "btn-lg btn-primary", value: "search" %>
          </div>
      <% end %>`

and a hash  before I submit like this:

`Parameters: { "query"=>"lorem ipsum dolor" ... }`

When I wait this:

`<input type="text" name="query" />`

How I can fix it?

Comment: Paste your code in a question.

Comment: Hi Darshan, your question is not really clear.  Are you getting any specific errors which you can share with us?

Comment: Hey @Darshan paste exact code you have here for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `form_for questions_path`. Instead, you should put the object, probably `@question` in your case.

Comment: Hi. I finally understand where I wrong. Where text_field I should use text_field_tag.